# Long text is not shown in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

In an Android application I use a WebView to show HTML text. Sometimes this text is very long. In this case the text is not shown. When I delete a sentence, the text is shown in my WebView. In a WebView is there a maximum character limit?

```
string myText = "<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            background: transparent; foreground: black;
        }
        .linkcolor {
            color: #80b936;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>My Content<br/>&nbsp;</body></html>"
```

> WebView.LoadData(myText, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Removing a sentence would cause the WebView to display correctly, adding it back would cause the WebView to be empty.

In my case, I had a ScrollView owning a LinearLayout owning the WebView. I removed the ScrollView and the WebView started to work just fine. WebView offers scrolling by itself, so you don't need the ScrollView.

I hope that that was your problem.

Comment: Not sure if it was his problem, but it was my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872669/android-4-long-html-in-webview) question. 
Setting `android:layerType` on the xml from `"software"` to `"none"` solve the problem.

You can also do this programatically:

```
myWebview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
```

You can also check out `setLayerType(int layerType, Paint paint)` [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Answer (score 1):

I would take care with your use of double quotes (") as it might be causing issues with your strings. I am not sure your example would actually work so you may have to show a sample of what works and what doesn't.

Something like this might work (I changed some double quotes to single quotes):

```
String myText = "<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <style type='text/css'>
        html, body {
            background: transparent; foreground: black;
        }
        .linkcolor {
            color: #80b936;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>My Content<br/>&nbsp;</body></html>";
```

Comment: after  struggling of five hours I got this, Thanks and Alhamdulillah.

Answer (score 0):

There is no artificial upper limit on the size of the text in the WebView (other than the amount of RAM on the device).

If you're running Android 4.4 (KitKat) you might be hitting an internal buffer size limit (which is around 20MB IIRC) but it seems a bit unlikely that adding/removing a sentence changes would push you above/below the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML have `<img>` or `<script>` tags?
If so, remember, that according to HTML DOM parser, if your HTML starts with an external resource, it will try to download that external resource before it proceeds to render the text below that. 
So, if the resource download is slow for some reason, you will see a blank page.
Possible solution:

1. Include JS as async or at the end
2. Keep CSS of `<img>` as `display:none` in either inline CSS or in a CSS `<style>` tag declared before the HTML
3. Have a JS script inline, which changes the CSS property of images back to `display:block`

That said, Since Android WebView is [bug-ridden](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android%20webview%20buggy&oq=android%20webview%20bug&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.17167j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) and is a complicated beast to handle as it is, I'm considering rendering my project in native entirely using TextViews and ImageViews.

Hope this helps! :)